# "Правильный" вывод переменных в PHP

Tags: php, переменные

Странный вопрос, но всё же.
Как красивее на PHP выводить переменные, если неизвестно, инициализированы ли они? 
То есть, там могут быть данные, а может и пустая быть. К примеру, в поля формы подставляются значения от запроса, не все из которых обязательные.
Можно проверять, конечно, всё `isset`'ами, и, если `false`, то не выводить или заменять какой-то заглушкой (в зависимости от нужд).
А какие есть варианты сделать короче и удобнее? С первого раза в голову приходит только мини-функция, куда передаёшь имя переменной из запроса, а она `isset`'ом проверяет, и либо переменную возвращает, либо null. Тогда можно удобно просто её подставлять. Но её ж не приспособить под вещи, которые не с запроса приходят.

Comment: > Но её ж не приспособить под вещи, которые не с запроса приходят.

почему? о каких вещах говорим?

Comment: то что приходит с запроса - это уже определенные переменные, если например пустая $row['title'] из запроса - тут и empty() и isset() вернут true, такчто isset'ами запросы проверять не вариант)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)